# strip html tags from data stored by users in html

Tags: php

i am working on project, in main page we display users detail and every user update its detail him self and we also allow HTML tags in detail.

but the problem what i am facing is, if person add some HTML detail like

```
<p><span style="color:#4c4c4c;font-family:Verdana;">Graphic Designer. Contact ***** .</span></p>
```

but on index page we display few character of detail and it comes to main page like this

```
<p><span style="color:#4c4c4c;font-family:Verda
```

this disturb all structure of main page.

i have tried PHP function

```
strip_tags
```

this did't work for me and i also write my own function to strip these tags on main page

```
function strip_html_tags( $text )
{
    $text = preg_replace(
        array(
          // Remove invisible content
            '@<head[^>]*?>.*?</head>@siu',
            '@<style[^>]*?>.*?</style>@siu',
            '@<script[^>]*?.*?</script>@siu',
            '@<object[^>]*?.*?</object>@siu',
            '@<embed[^>]*?.*?</embed>@siu',
            '@<applet[^>]*?.*?</applet>@siu',
            '@<noframes[^>]*?.*?</noframes>@siu',
            '@<noscript[^>]*?.*?</noscript>@siu',
            '@<noembed[^>]*?.*?</noembed>@siu',

            '@</?((address)|(blockquote)|(center)|(del))@iu',
            '@</?((div)|(h[1-9])|(ins)|(isindex)|(p)|(pre))@iu',
            '@</?((dir)|(dl)|(dt)|(dd)|(li)|(menu)|(ol)|(ul))@iu',
            '@</?((table)|(th)|(td)|(caption))@iu',
            '@</?((form)|(button)|(fieldset)|(legend)|(input))@iu',
            '@</?((label)|(select)|(optgroup)|(option)|(textarea))@iu',
            '@</?((frameset)|(frame)|(iframe))@iu',
        ),
        array(
            ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ',"$0", "$0", "$0", "$0", "$0", "$0","$0", "$0",), $text );


    return strip_tags( $text);
}
```

this also did't work.

what i need is: to strip all html tags for proper display on main page.

Thanks

Comment: Whyhow didn't `strip_tags()` work? Please post the code you used it in.

Comment: _why_ does `strip_tags` not work for you, what problem are you having with that?

Comment: Having said that, why not just escape the output with htmlentities?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`strip_tags()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php) is built into PHP

[HTML Purifier](http://htmlpurifier.org/) is even more robust solution

Comment: HTMLPurifier _is_ great, but he wants to just totally strip HTML it seems (i.e. not allow it at all), so htmlentities/specialchars would work.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered simply using `html_entities()`? This replaces '<' with '&lt;' and '>' with '&gt;' among other things. It allows you to echo it to the page without worrying too much about it interfering with the page.

Answer (score 0):

Is your person information not just saved as entities instead of plain text? That would explain why strip_tags doesn't work.

In that case use: [html_entity_decode](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.html-entity-decode.php) to display the actual HTML